# Akka actors, Futures, and closures

Tags: scala, closures, actor, akka, future

I read in the [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/actors.html#Creating_Actors_using_anonymous_classes) that it's dangerous to close over variables from an enclosing actor.

> **Warning**
>
> In this case you need to carefully avoid closing over the
> containing actor’s reference, i.e. do not call methods on the
> enclosing actor from within the anonymous Actor class. This would
> break the actor encapsulation and may introduce synchronization bugs
> and race conditions because the other actor’s code will be scheduled
> concurrently to the enclosing actor.

Now, I have two actors, one of which requests something from the second and does something with the result. In this example below I have put together, actor *Accumulator* retrieves numbers from actor *NumberGenerator* and adds them up, reporting the sum along the way.

This can be done in at least two different ways as this example shows with two different *receive* functions (*A* vs *B*). The difference between the two is that *A* does not close over the *counter* variable; instead it awaits an integer and sums it up, while *B* creates a *Future* that closes over *counter* and does the sum. This happens within an anonymous actor created just to process onSuccess, if I understand properly how this works.

```
import com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log

import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}
import akka.pattern.{ask, pipe}
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.util.duration._

case object Start
case object Request


object ActorTest {
  var wake = 0

  val accRef = Main.actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Accumulator], name = "accumulator")
  val genRef = Main.actorSystem.actorOf(Props[NumberGenerator], name = "generator")

  Log.info("ActorTest", "Starting !")

  accRef ! Start
}

class Accumulator extends Actor {
  var counter = 0

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  // A: WITHOUT CLOSURE
  def receive = {
    case Start => ask(ActorTest.genRef, Request).mapTo[Int] pipeTo self
    case x: Int => counter += x; Log.info("Accumulator", "counter = " + counter); self ! Start
  }
  // B: WITH CLOSURE
  def receive = {
    case Start => ask(ActorTest.genRef, Request).mapTo[Int] onSuccess {
      case x: Int => counter += x; Log.info("Accumulator", "counter = " + counter); self ! Start
    }
  }
}

class NumberGenerator extends Actor {
  val rand = new java.util.Random()

  def receive = {
    case Request => sender ! rand.nextInt(11)-5
  }
}
```

Is it absolutely evil to use closures in this case ? Of course I could use an AtomicInteger instead of an Int, or in some networking scenario using, say, [netty](http://netty.io/), issue a write operation on a [threadsafe](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/netty-users/2009-October/001453.html) channel, but this is not my point here.

To the risk of asking the ridiculous: is there a way for the Future's onSuccess to execute in **this** actor instead of an anonymous middle actor, **without** defining a case in the *receive* function ?

**EDIT**

To put it more clearly, my question is: Is there a way to force a series of Futures to run in the same thread as a given Actor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `onSuccess` is going to run in a different thread than the thread the actor's `receive` is going to run in.   You could use the `pipeTo` approach, or use an [Agent](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/agents.html).  Making `counter` an `AtomicInteger` would solve the problem, but it's not so clean - that is, it breaks the Actor model.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way of implementing such design is by using "fire-and-forget" semantic:

```
class Accumulator extends Actor {
  private[this] var counter = 0

  def receive = {
    case Start => ActorTest.genRef ! Request
    case x: Int => {
      counter += x
      Log.info("Accumulator", "counter = " + counter)
      self ! Start
    }
  }
}
```

This solution is fully asynchronous, and you don't need any timeout.

Comment: Yes, this works if I would give up using Futures. Chaining Futures is readily possible in my example if they end with _pipeTo self_ but is not possible anymore with the fire-and-forget semantic. Instead, I would have to define N intermediate messages in the Accumulator's receive function only to guarantee code is run within this Actor's thread. I think I can ask again, this time more clearly: is there a way to force a series of Futures to run in the same thread as a given Actor ?

Comment: Why do you need to guarantee that the `Accumulator` Actor always run in the same thread ? That seems to be against actor-model philosophy. The same for futures: they should be dispatched on a thread pool such as to maximize performances. If they all run in the same thread in a chain, you just have a plain sequential program and you don't need futures anymore...

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if it's run in the same thread or not, the requirement is more that it should be run sequentially, just as the messages of a single actor are processed. This doesn't go against the actor model, it _is_ the actor model.

Comment: You can chain `Future`s using actors: just use `?` (`ask`) instead of `!` (`tell`): you'll get a `Future` back, which you can `map` and `fold`over: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/futures.html