# Await.result always hangs/timeout and never returns result (Scala - Akka actors)

Tags: scala, akka, actor

To make an inefficient story short, I am trying to make a Scala actor system which computes Fibonacci numbers. However, the Await.result() lines always timeout, and I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
class FibMachine extends Actor {
    implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case 0 => sender ! 0
        case 1 => sender ! 0
        case x: Int if x > 1 => {
            val child = context.actorOf(Props(new FibMachine()))
            val self_num: Int = Await.result((self ? (x - 1)).mapTo[Int], timeout.duration)
            val child_num: Int = Await.result((child ? (x - 2)).mapTo[Int], timeout.duration)
            child ! PoisonPill
            sender ! self_num + child_num
        }
    }
}
```

What is the simplest way to fix this issue?

Searched online, didn't get any useful results.

Comment: You shall not do any blocking call in an Actor.

Comment: These might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130003/akka-actors-futures-and-closures, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618738/return-future-message-from-an-actor

Comment: Actors process messages one by one. In your processing for `x > 1` you are asking the same actor the response for `x - 1`, anf then you are waiting on the response. But the actor will not process the next message untill it is done with current one. So... your actor is basically waiting on itself. Althogh it is not a good way to use actors, but your current code will start working if you create another child actor to ask for `x-1` like you are doing for `x-2`. .

Comment: This will work as long as the number of threads in your actor-systme is more than the total number of awaits among all created actors. After then you will start bumping into thread exhausion

Answer (score 1):

Actors process one message at a time, and do not process the next message until `receive` has returned for the current message. An actor cannot send a message to itself and then block waiting for a reply because that second message cannot be processed until the `receive` call for first message is complete. So `Await.result((self ? ...` is always going to fail when the `?` times out.

The simple fix is to send both queries to `child` rather than sending the first one to `self`. It will be massively inefficient and probably run out of resources for large numbers but at least it won't hang.

It is also worth noting that the first two terms of the Fibonacci sequence are `1`, not `0`. As it stands the code will always return `0`.